# Как сделать вывод посчитанных данных JS

Tags: javascript, html

Мне необходимо, чтобы человек ввел цифры в форму, нажал кнопку посчитать и у него вылезло диалогое окно с результатом.
Не понимаю, что не так в коде.

```js
const form = document.getElementById('form');
form.addEventListener('submit', getFormValue);

function getFormValue(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var speed = "";
  var interval = "";
  var length = "";
  speed = form.querySelector('[name="v"]'), //получаем поле v
    interval = form.querySelector('[name="interval"]'),
    length = form.querySelector('[name="length"]');
  const data = {
    name: name.value,
    age: age.value,
    plan: plan.value,
    terms: terms.checked
  };
  ps = (length / speed) / interval

  alert(ps);
};
```

```css
body {
  height: 90%;
}

.avtor {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <form>
    <input type="number" name="length"><br>
    <input type="number" name="v"><br>
    <input type="number" name="interval"><br>
    <button type="submit">Посчитать!</button>
  </form>
</body>

<footer>
  <div class="avtor">
    <center></center>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: У вас функция getFormValue вызывается?

Comment: ***Не понимаю, что не так в коде.*** - Мы тоже не понимаем. А что у вас не так работает когда запускаете код - ошибки, предупреждения, бездействие?

Comment: @eccs0103 У тебя сегодня тоже хрустальный шар предвидения и предсказания не работает?

Comment: @SwaD, к сожалению, да! Разрядился позавчера и не запускается.

Comment: @eccs0103 вообще ничего не работает, просто в гет-запрос отдаются переменные и все.

Comment: Прикрепите html.

Comment: Попробуйте обработчик повесить не на фарму, а на кнопку, которая нажимается для отправки формы.

Comment: У вас ошибка. Вы ищете элемент с идентификатором `form`, тем временем вы не создали что-то с этим идентификатором.

Comment: А во поводу общего кода... 1. не пишите ничего вне `body`, 2. не используйте тег `<center>` - оно не поддерживается, 3. не используйте не определенные переменные, такой как `ps`, 4. `var` используется для создании глобальных переменных. Такие переменные видны везде и даже в других скриптах. Постарайтесь использовать его минимально. Используйте `let`

Answer (score 0):

Вот исправленный вариант, всего возможного, что можно было исправить.
В комментарий взял `data`, так как не понятно откуда оно берет значения и так же препятствует работе кода.

```js
const form = document.querySelector(`form#my-form`);
form.addEventListener(`submit`, (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  const speed = form.querySelector(`[name="v"]`);
  const interval = form.querySelector(`[name="interval"]`);
  const length = form.querySelector(`[name="length"]`);
  /* const data = {
    name: name.value,
    age: age.value,
    plan: plan.value,
    terms: terms.checked
  }; */
  alert((length.value / speed.value) / interval.value);
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 90%;
}

.avtor {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <form id="my-form">
    <input type="number" name="length"><br>
    <input type="number" name="v"><br>
    <input type="number" name="interval"><br>
    <button type="submit">Посчитать!</button>
  </form>
  <footer>
    <div class="avtor"></div>
  </footer>
</body>
```

Comment: Не отрабатывает, выдает в ответе NaN.

Comment: @dyvaraZrab потому что вы разделяли элементы, а не их значения. Если к каждому добавить `.value` то сработает.